# SQL where clause giving a null result

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, where-clause

I have the following simple php code that gives me a result that I want to display.

```
$linkz= mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db, $linkz);


$sq_name= $_POST['unameTF'];
$sq_pass= $_POST['passTF'];
$sq_search= $_POST['searchTF'];

if($sq_search=""||$sq_search=null)
{
echo "type something";
}else
{
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM sql_insert WHERE sq_name='$sq_search' ";
$res= mysql_query($sql2, $linkz) or die(mysql_error());
}

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    }
    echo "$row[sq_name]"."<br/>";
    }
```

This gives me a null result always(ie it doesn't give an error or dispay anything).
It works fine when the if-else statement is removed meaning it just

```
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM sql_insert WHERE sq_name='$sq_search' ";
$res= mysql_query($sql2, $linkz) or die(mysql_error());
```

and no checking to see if its null.

and also if I replace

```
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM sql_insert WHERE sq_name='$sq_search' ";
```

with

```
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM sql_insert WHERE sq_name='".$_POST['searchTF']."' ";
```

(even without removing the if-else statement)

Can someone explain whats going on?

Comment: Please note that `mysql` is not supported anymore. Use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Yeah thanks @Nytrix &@Jay. I know you shouldn't use mysql any longer cause of sql injection. This is more of a homework DB/php project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it works without the `if()` statement is because you used assignment operators, rather than comparison operators causing the flow of your if statement to work like this:

```
if we can set $sq_search = "" ... we can!
    check that it's not a null-terminated value... that's good too!
if we can set $sq_search = null ... we can!
    check that it's not a null-terminated value... it is, this answer is false
do that else statement,
    compile the string, output will be: "SELECT * FROM sql_insert WHERE sq_name=''"
```

replace your if statement with this:

```
if($sq_search===""||is_null($sq_search)){
    echo "type something";
} else {
    $sql2= "SELECT * FROM sql_insert WHERE sq_name='$sq_search' ";
    $res= mysql_query($sql2, $linkz) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((!isset($_POST['searchTF'])) || (empty($_POST['searchTF']))
{
echo "type something";
} else
```

Comment: what happens if the contents of `$_POST['searchTF']` is `'0'` ??

Comment: Then it searches for zero... :/     but yes, the initial problem is due to not using comparators .. 
    if ($var=0) { 
    }      // always true  

    if ($var==0) { 
    }      // only true if $var contains 0

Comment: actually `empty('0')` will evaluate to true causing the `echo "type something";` to evaluate rather than searching like you'd expect. :)

Comment: DOH!  I meant 
     if ($var=='0') { }          

good catch!